# Missing widget - how do I load one (Discretize)

Tags: python, data-mining, orange

In ORANGE - I found that the Discretize widget is missing in my installation - where do I go to load it?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please see the manual, or e.g. Orange user forums / mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was due to an old version of numpy being installed prior to installing Orange on a windows install. The Orange installer did not upgrade numpy even though for some widgets it requires it (the discretize widget being one of them which then fails to load silently^).

Uninstalling numpy and rerunning the orange installer (which then installed a current version of numpy) fixed the issue.

^ Silently with respect to the interface - errors were shown in canvas.log which can be found in C:\Users\[your_username]\AppData\Local\Orange Canvas